# Use ngFor component with different templates

Tags: angular, components

I'm new to Angular 4. I made a component to display a dynamic list :

UPDATED CODE WITH CRASH ANSWER :

My list.component.html

```
<ion-list class="list">
  <ion-item class="list-item" *ngFor="let decompte of decomptes">
    <div class="list-item-date">
        <p class="month" text-wrap>{{decompte.date | limitTo : 6}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item-type">
        <span class="info">{{decompte.name}}</span>
        <span class="legend">{{decompte.actes}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item-price">
        <span class="info">{{decompte.price}} €</span>
        <span class="legend">{{decompte.tiers}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item-btn">
        <ion-icon class="icon ion-ios-arrow_right"></ion-icon>
    </div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I call it in a first template, and I need to use it too in another template, but I have to limit to the 3 last items, and don't display all of them.

My template : 
dashboard.html

```
<div class="dashboard-decomptes">
  <list-component limit="3"></list-component>
  <button ion-button clear (click)="goToStatements()">Consulter tous mes décomptes</button>
</div>
```

And the component ts file :

list.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Input } from '@angular/core';


@Component({

selector: 'list-component',
templateUrl: './list.component.html'
})

export class listComponent {

//Temp fake news
public decomptes = [{
    date: '12 Janvier',
    name: 'toto',
    price: '122,25',
    tiers: 'tutu',
    actes : "+ 2 actes"
}, ....]

@Input() limit: number;

}
```

I don't know how to do add the limit in a specific template. If anyone has an idea..
Thanks by advance !

Comment: please let me know if my answer worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone want to know the final solution :

list.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Input } from '@angular/core';


@Component({

selector: 'list-component',
templateUrl: './list.component.html'
})

export class listComponent {

//Temp fake news
public decomptes = [{
    date: '12 Janvier',
    name: 'Pharmacie',
    price: '122,25',
    tiers: 'tiers-payant',
    actes : "+ 2 actes"
},...]

@Input() limit: number;

}
```

list.component.html

```
<ion-list class="list">
<ion-item class="list-item" *ngFor="let decompte of decomptes.slice(0, limit)">
    <div class="list-item-date">
        <p class="month" text-wrap>{{decompte.date | limitTo : 6}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item-type">
        <span class="info">{{decompte.name}}</span>
        <span class="legend">{{decompte.actes}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item-price">
        <span class="info">{{decompte.price}} €</span>
        <span class="legend">{{decompte.tiers}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item-btn">
        <ion-icon class="icon ion-ios-arrow_right"></ion-icon>
    </div>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And the template where I only need the three last items :

```
<list-component limit="3"></list-component>
```

Thanks a lot to Crash who gave me the whole solution.

Answer (score 2):

In your `list-component` pass the limit as input

```
<list-component limit="3"></list-component>
```

and then inside `ListComponent` retrieve it with

```
@Input() limit: number;
```

also remember to import the Input decorator

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
```

Then, to limit the nr of elements shown you can do something like

```
<ion-item class="list-item" *ngFor="let decompte of decomptes.reverse().slice(0, limit+1)">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quickly answer. I updated my code with your suggestion, but it doesn't change. Let me know if I made something wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry I just realized your question was actually different, let me update my answer

Comment: Ok, check my updated answer and let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks for the update, but unfortunately, it doesn't work. In the template where I need only three items, i got all of them, and inside the template where I need to see all, nothing is display.

Comment: Maybe it's because when I write limit="3", it's applied to the component who doesn't start with the item repeater, but by a container

Comment: the first piece of code of your question is `list.component.html` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147823/discussion-between-crash-and-quentin-icky).

Comment: Yes that's it, I'll update my question to be more clear.